# How to enable Rumble/Vibrate on Gamepad

Tags: wine, dolphin, gamepad, emulation

I've been trying to search for solutions for days now but still to no avail. It's really starting to frustrate me.

See I have this gamepad (DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick) which is functioning great except the rumble effect.

I've tried installing in on a Windows system through VM and another in a Windows PC and at both times, the rumble effect worked.

But the thing is, even on the Windows systems, the rumble effect needed a driver for it to work which I also installed on my Ubuntu using Wine. (I'm not sure if THAT's the issue)

And on another note, when I was on Windows, the emulator I was using to test the rumble effect (Dolphin) there were two choices on the dropdown menu for installed joystick devices. One of which is "DInput/0/USB Vibration Stick" and the other one is "SDL/0/USB Vibration Stick". Both of them are my DragonRise Joystick BUT if I chose the DInput, the rumble effect works, and if I chose the SDL it WONT WORK.

Screenshot:

[image]

When I went to try on the Dolphin Emulator in Ubuntu, and clicked the dropdown menu, ONLY  the "SDL" appeared and there is no "DInput" on the choices.

Screenshot:

[image]

My question, how do I install my gamepad on Ubuntu so that the DInput WILL appear together with the SDL? I have a feeling the rumble effect will work once it's installed.

Sorry for the long post. I hope I will get a response soon. I'm really getting frustrated.

P.S. What are DInput and SDL anyway?